# Time on each page in joomla site

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Can any one help in storing the time spent by user on each page in Joomla before they logout?

and also, how do we store the form submitted by user after login to Joomla?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your issue yourself?

Answer (score 0):

On any new page, calculate the $time1 = time()
Before you move to any new page calculate $time2 = time()
Subtract the first time from the second one and record the number of seconds for the specific page in the database.!